# Adding trailing Zero after decimal in c#

Tags: c#, html

I have numbers like 22.2300 , 12, 3.4000, 0.0000 I would like to display them as 22.230, 12, 3.40 and 0.0 ... What is th ebest way to acheive this?

I have look around but not very successful.

Please help here

Comment: how is this related to _html_?

Answer (score 5):

Use a string format. Example:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: But, the value will be converted as a string. I don't need to convert decimal value as string. Any other method to add trailing zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", 111.2); //111.20
Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", 111.222); //111.22
Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", 111.229); //111.23
```

Another way to do it is with string.format, the way shown above